# .comma / surprising / capitalization

Tags: word-choice, commas, capitalization

I'm not a native English speaker, and I have specific concerns about the following text:

> After starting my education in Veterinary Medicine and beginning to know diseases and issues that cause problems for animals and their owners**, [comma]** I have learned that poisoning was one of the most common problem which we had to deal with it. The interesting thing about poisoning is its diversity. It seemed **surprising** to me that beside of famous and notorious toxins, many essential elements and substances like Calcium, Sodium and even **water** can be considered toxins."

1. Is this correct to use a comma in this situation (for animals and their owners, I have learned...)?
2. Does it make sense to use *surprising* in this sentence? ("It seemed surprising to me that beside of famous and notorious toxins...")
3. Shouldn't *water* start with a capital letter? ("...many essential elements and substances like Calcium, Sodium and even **water** can be considered toxins.")

Comment: I think you'd get better / more detailed answers if you asked this question on [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This passage isn't an example of well-written grammatical English. For instance, there shouldn't be an *"it"* in *"which we had to deal with it"*. The tenses don't seem to be consistent to me, either; that *"had"* should be a *"have"*. And the *"of"* after *"beside"* is wrong.

Comment: Also asked on ELL: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39410/comma-surprising-capitalization

Comment: @JasonC Yes, because the OP was advised to by Dan Bron in first comment above!! :)

Comment: Thank you sir for your correction.I wrote this and all in all,do you think that was a disastrous writing or acceptable one for a non native person?

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, that is how I interpreted Dan's comment as well.

Comment: @JasonC Ah, very sorry - thought you were complaining about poor old OP ;)

Comment: Please [edit] the title to ask an actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The comma looks correct to me, as the sentence needs a pause there.  It is a single sentence of the form "*After [doing something], I have [done another thing]*".  That said, it is a very long and wordy sentence and would be better split in two.
2. I see no problem in the use of "surprising".
3. Water is just a noun, rather than a "proper noun" and so doesn't need to be capitalised (unless it's the first word of a sentence, like here).  It would be better if Calcuim and Soduim weren't capitalised either.